# Python: how to make conditional operations in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` like the following

```
df   A   B    C
0    1   0.7 0.3
1    0   0.2 0.8
2    0   0.8 0.2
3    1   0.6 0.4
4    1   0.9 0.1
```

I want to create a column `D` that has values `(1-B) if A==1` or `(1-C) if A==0`. So

```
df   A   B    C    D
0    1   0.7 0.3  0.3
1    0   0.2 0.8  0.2
2    0   0.8 0.2  0.8
3    1   0.6 0.4  0.4
4    1   0.9 0.1  0.1
```

Answer (score 4):

If sum by `B` and `C` columns get `1` is possible use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) without subtracting:

```
df['D'] = np.where(df['A'] == 0, df['B'], df['C'])
print (df)
   A    B    C    D
0  1  0.7  0.3  0.3
1  0  0.2  0.8  0.2
2  0  0.8  0.2  0.8
3  1  0.6  0.4  0.4
```

If want use formula and `A` column contains only `1` and `0` values:

```
df['D'] = np.where(df['A'] == 0, 1 - df['C'], 1 - df['B'])
print (df)
   A    B    C    D
0  1  0.7  0.3  0.3
1  0  0.2  0.8  0.2
2  0  0.8  0.2  0.8
3  1  0.6  0.4  0.4
4  1  0.9  0.1  0.1
```

If possible multiple values in `A` column (most general solution) use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
print (df)
   A    B    C
0  1  0.7  0.3
1  0  0.2  0.8
2  0  0.8  0.2
3  1  0.6  0.4
4  3  0.9  0.1 <- added 3

m1 = df['A'] == 0
m2 = df['A'] == 1
df['D'] = np.select([m1, m2], [1 - df['C'], 1 - df['B']], default=np.nan)
print (df)
   A    B    C    D
0  1  0.7  0.3  0.3
1  0  0.2  0.8  0.2
2  0  0.8  0.2  0.8
3  1  0.6  0.4  0.4
4  3  0.9  0.1  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.select()` and `np.where()` are the way to go.

One more option, can also do

```
df.loc[df.A == 1, 'D'] = 1 - df.B
df.loc[df.A == 0, 'D'] = 1 - df.C
```